# Error while using dplyr package (Select function is not working)

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I just began to learn `R`. I am trying to use the `dplyr` package to manipulate data. While using the select function, this is the error that pops up.

`dplyr::select(flights, DepTime, ArrTime, FlightNum)`

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘rlang’

I'm really lost and have no idea how to proceed. Any insight would be much appreciated. I have installed and called the `dplyr` library. Still, none of the `dplyr` functions seem to be working.

Comment: either re-install `dplyr` with dependencies, e.g. `install.packages("dplyr",dependencies=TRUE)` or just install the dependent package by itself with `install.packages("rlang")` then do `library(dplyr)` again -- sometimes this happens when a CRAN repository has a (usually temporarily) corrupt package and you download it

Comment: Also make sure that you restart your R session